# How do I enable the column selection mode in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, text-editor, eclipse-3.5

News wrote that Eclipse 3.5 finally supports column selection. 
Unfortunately I don't know HOW to enable it. I tried pressing the ALT-key like I am used to in Visual Studio and all other Microsoft products but that had no effect.

How can I mark a vertical block in Eclipse?

Answer (score 511, accepted):

To **activate** the cursor and select the columns you want to select use:

> Windows:
>   <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
>
> Mac: <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
>
> Linux-based OS:
>   <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

To **deactivate**, press the keys again.

This information was taken from [DJ's Java Blog](http://deepakjacob.blogspot.com/2009/05/eclispe-35-column-section-mode.html).

Comment: I see, it is a whole "mode" that needs to be enabled.

Comment: alt+shift+a dnw for me on osx

Comment: alt+shift+a is not working in my eclipse. how to enable it from the eclipse?

Comment: I think it's an Eclipse 3 or 3.5 feature?

Comment: This is not working for me in Android Developer Tools Build: v22.0.5-757759

edit: Look down Android devs!

Comment: For Eclipse Kepler on Mavericks its `command` + `option` + `A`

Comment: Ohh.. it works.. but it feels so primitive compared to Textmate, Sublime, Atom....

Comment: If it doesn't work for you, try to start marking text normally and while the selection is there, click the alt-shift-a

Comment: In my Eclipse it works for .java files but not for .md files... I guess it's not in the generoc Structured Text Editor but only in some of the more specific editors... Beats me why, seems to me column editing is a generic option.

Comment: A little off topic but if you were an eclipse editor developer, what library or functions would you use to implement this feature (i.e., pressing Alt + Shift + A simultaneously switches the mouse cursor to "block select")?

Answer (score 123):

On Windows and Linux, it's <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, as RichieHindle pointed out.  On OSX it's <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>).  It's also worth noting that the two modes can have different font preferences, so if you've changed the default text font, it can be jarring to toggle block selection modes and see the font change.

Finally, the "search commands" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>) pop-up will find it for you if you type block.  This is useful if you use the feature just frequently enough to forget the hotkey.

Comment: To modify the font in this selection mode: Eclipse -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts -> Basic -> Text Editor Block Selection Font.

Comment: Is there a way to enable column mode select when looking in the console or JUnit console view?  Alt-Shift-A only works in the source code editing window / view.

Comment: I don't see any way to enable block selection in the console -- you could copy the content out to an Eclipse buffer and then select there.

Answer (score 66):

[As RichieHindle pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053725/how-do-i-enable-the-column-selection-mode-in-eclipse/1053745#1053745) the shortcut for column (block) selection is `Alt+Shift+A`. The problem I ran into is that the Android SDK on Eclipse uses 3 shortcuts that all start with `Alt+Shift+A`, so if you type that, you'll be given a choice of continuing with `D`, `S`, or `R`.

To solve this I redefined the column selection as `Alt+Shift+A,A` (`Alt`, `Shift`, `A` pressed together and then followed by a subsequent `A`). To do this go to `Windows > Preferences` then type `keys` or navigate to `General > Keys`. Under the **Keys** enter the `filter text` of `block selection` to quickly find the shortcut listing for `toggle block selection`. Here you can adjust the shortcut for column selection as you wish.

Comment: it's a very useful information for Android developers. thank you.

Comment: That was easy. Great utility for all Android devs. Thank you!

Comment: Especially nice to put the instructions here... I was searching for `toggle block selection` in the Keys entry already, but I had no idea what the name was...

Comment: I wish there was a way to get rid of the anoying android als+shift+a choices :( and no I don't have the android plugin installed as far as I can tell)

Comment: I unbound all the other ALT+Shift+A commands and toggle block selection isn't working as a hotkey currently. EDIT: Restarting ADT fixed the hotkey issue. Alt+Shift+A is working fine now.

Comment: @AmanicA You can easily unbind the Android plugin's shortcuts from the above-mentioned Keys dialog. However, if you don't have the Android plugin installed, then you don't have its shortcuts either.

Answer (score 28):

First of all your mouse key must be focus in editor to enable **Toggle Block Selection Mode**

[image]

Click on `toggleButton` as shown in figure and it will `enable Vertical selection`. After selection toggle it again.

Comment: This works on ADT, also it shows that the shortcut is **Alt+Shift+A** but that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot.  The keyboard shortcuts listed here assume the shortcut actually works.  Since that is non-visual, pointing to the button is a great reference.  Plus, the button indicates its shortcut key with a tool-tip.  In this case, the ALT+SHIFT+A solution, which does not work in the Android Developer Tools v22.0.1-685705.

Comment: This option is also available under Edit >> Toggle Block Selection.

Answer (score 16):

Additionally, you can change the keys view window -> preferences then type: 'keys' and when the key preference page opens you can type 'toggle block selection' and voila!

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am new to the Eclipse IDE and only knew the "Key-Assist" window.

Answer (score 10):

You can enable and disable column editing mode via the keyboard shortcut `ALT-SHIFT-A`.

Once enabled you can then use either the mouse to select a block of text, or the keyboard using `SHIFT` (like a normal keyboard select, except the selection will now be in a block).

If you've changed your default font for text editing, entering column editing mode will probably change your screen font to the default column editing font (which is probably different to your changed font.  To change the font when in column editing mode, go to the menu and select `Window -> Preferences`, then in the tree on the left hand side, pick `General -> Appearance -> Colors and Fonts`, and then pick `Basic -> Text Editor Block Selection Font` on the right hand side tree.  You can then select the font to be consistent with your "not in column editing mode" font.

Answer (score 8):

A different approach:

The [vrapper](http://vrapper.sf.net) plugin emulates `vim` inside the Eclipse editor. One of its features is `visual block` mode which works fine inside Eclipse.

It is by default mapped to `Ctrl-V` which interferes with the paste command in Eclipse. You can either remap the `visual block` mode to a different shortcut, or remap the `paste` command to a different key. I chose the latter: remapped the `paste` command to `Ctrl-Shift-V` to match my terminal's behavior.

Answer (score 1):

- Press Alt + Shift + A
- Observe that the screen zooms out
- Make selection using the mouse
- Press Alt + Shift + A to go back to the old mode.
  [image]