# How to have eclipse add line comments at the indent instead at the beginning of the line?

Tags: eclipse

When running **Toggle Comment** on one or more lines of code, Eclipse adds the comment (*//*) at the beginning of the line.  Is it possible to have Eclipse add the line comment where the code is indented at instead?

This can be fixed by running **Source > Format** but it would be nice if it can be done automatically when Toggling Comment.

Comment: Instead of pressing `ctrl + /` manually type `//` on the new line.

Comment: That's a horrible answer if you have 50 lines of code to comment. I'd like to see a proper answer to this question too.

Comment: It was [already reported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225951/eclipse-toggle-comment-indented) and the bottomline is that Eclipse team does not want to have it done: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=321092

Comment: The unwillingness of the Eclipse team to make this happen is so frustrating.

Comment: another arrogant "we know better" dev team after gnome and chrome devs... I am so sick of this....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround solution is to have Eclipse do the formatting automatically: you can enable this through the "Save Action" preference.