# Clearing output from Scala Worksheet

Tags: scala, scala-ide

Every-time you save a Scala Worksheet in the Scala IDE, the output of each expression is printed as comments on the right-hand side of the editor. Is there a way to clear this output from a Scala Worksheet so that you can cut and paste code?

Currently, my solution is to save my worksheet with an error, so that the output would disappear. There must be a better way... a keyboard shortcut or something.

Comment: If the answer turns out to be no, please submit a feature request. That's definitely something we should have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such feature yet. There is a related ticket: [The Format action should strip comments.](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet/issues/92)

Comment: Thanks for opening a ticket Iulian.

Answer (score 4):

While waiting for the ticket to be resolved, this regular expression can be used in Find/Replace (Ctrl/Cmd+F) to delete the comments.

```
 *//[>|].*$
```

***Update:***
This has been fixed: [#132](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet/issues/132)

Answer (score 2):

It's jerry-rigged, but gets the job done.

1. Make a small edit (e.g. delete a space where it doesn't matter) to prompt a save.
2. Save.
3. Press Esc immediately to terminate worksheet process.

You now have a clean worksheet!

Answer (score 2):

**Ctrl+Shift+C** does the job in Scala IDE 4.7.0

Answer (score 1):

Alt+Shift+A enables **Block selection mode**.  You will be able to select only left part of screen (columns with code). Block mode also makes possible to select only columns with output.

[More on block selection mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053725/how-do-i-enable-the-column-selection-mode-in-eclipse)