# Eclipse Indigo "Shift+Alt+A" shortcut

Tags: android, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Eclipse Indigo for Android development. Eclipse provides many useful keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (block selection mode) or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> (run android app). The problem is these shortcuts doesn't work for me.

I've read a lot of topics here claiming that it is usually a problem with other programs installed on the computer. I am using Mint Nadia, Mint Maya (Cinnamon and MATE) on three different computers and none of them use the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> shortcut nor any other installed program.

It seems to me there is a conflict in Eclipse with these shortcuts. If you simply type the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, IDE recognizes the shortcut but you're prompted with a pop-up to choose the additional key (<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>R</kbd>). No matter which one you choose it does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal after installing the Android addon. Android adds three shortcuts that all begin that way.

Unfortunately, the only real option is to change the shortcut(either the block selection one, or all three Android ones).

Details on changing it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7862385/752320), if you're not sure how.

Comment: I've changed the block selection mode key binding to "Shift+Alt+A A" and this shortcut works perfect, but the Android' shortcuts still don't  work at all.

Comment: That's strange. If I change mine to match, they all work fine. Maybe because I'm using Juno instead of Indigo.

Comment: that was it ! Note: you may have to restart eclipse.