# Edit block of code in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, refactoring

I am wondering if there is a key command for editing a block of code in Eclipse. This a function that I use in Visual Studio - alt and select with the mouse cursor, when I need to change the type of some variables for example and they are one below the other.
Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer can be found from the documentation of the application.

Comment: Check [this](http://vasanth.in/2009/03/31/eclipse-tip-block-selection-mode/), [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/eclipses-awesome-block) and [this](http://www.robertwloch.net/2011/01/eclipse-tips-tricks-block-selection-mode/). Google it before asking question

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable the column selection mode in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053725/how-do-i-enable-the-column-selection-mode-in-eclipse)