# Selecting multiple pieces of text in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selection

A very simple question that may have been answered before but I couldn't find it. I was wondering if there is a possible way to selecting multiple pieces of text/code in Eclipse, without also selecting every text between. Just like the function of MS Word when you hold down the ctrl-button and pick and choose with the mouse what you would like to select. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053725/how-do-i-enable-the-column-selection-mode-in-eclipse ?

Comment: May I know why you need this?In any file explorer we can select multiple files with ctrl or shift key. We can use this to copy only selected files to other folders.Do you want to copy all selected texts to clipboard?

Comment: I am doing assignments which sometimes has solutions which we can copy to eclipse and see how it works. Problem is, these solutions are printed in a website and we dont get them in a java file. And it's printed with linenumbers so the code becomes somewhat like this.....1. "first line of code", 2 "second line of code", 3 third line of code" etc. I have to remove the 1, 2, 3...99 until the code works seperately since if I mark all at once i also end up marking the code. It's a hassle so I was wondering if there was a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no such capability built into Eclipse. There's always a chance that some third-party plug-in provides it, but in 10+ years as an Eclipse user and developer I've never heard of one.