# Column editor in Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, multiple-columns

Anyone knows if there is a column editor function in Oracle SQL Developer?

I have to modify the same column in a large number of insert statement and it would be really useful to have a column editor.

To explain better which is my problem i am searching a function similar to Eclipse ones when you type <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> ([How do I enable the column selection mode in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053725/how-do-i-enable-the-column-selection-mode-in-eclipse)), and it allow you to edit in one time a lot of columns.

There is something similar or i have to do it manually?

I am using **4.1.5.21** version.

Thanks

Comment: You can add extra cursors by ctrl+shift+click, but I can't find column editing in SQL Developer so would recommend UltraEdit instead.

Comment: i know that, but it's not like others software column editing. I don't think it's possible right now, maybe in the future. Thank you anyway for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit/Wrap Selection (enable it):

https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/07/how-to-block-select-text-in-oracle-sql-developer/

Just press Shift and move cursors up and down, etc.

Be careful to press Esc after each edition as it seems to "stick" or something and it keeps adding cursors and modifying where you don't expect it.

Trick: The multi-cursor is useful to edit several parts in the same line.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using a newer version of Oracle Sql Developer (at least 18.3.x but perhaps before) there is an even easier way.

Simply go to the "Edit" menu and then choose "Block Selection":

[image: Oracle SQL Developer Block Selection]

Comment: Legend. Thanks @risingTide. This answers my problem!