# What is the Oracle SQL Developer shortcut key for inserting duplicate strings into multiple columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a background in Teradata SQL programming and recently started working on Oracle SQL Developer. In Teradata, whenever I needed to write same code of lines, different only in few areas, I used to do `shift + alt + up`, write the code and it would insert it onto multiple lines which I have selected. Something like below:

[image]

1. In step 0, I would just copy the column list from a table
2. In 2nd step, I would press `shift + alt + up` and then press `up` enough number of times selecting the lines where I want to insert the code, and then start typing `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT`  in front of let's `COLUMN_P`, but it would parallelly copy same code in front of selected lines.
3. In 3rd step, I would do the same thing, and this time writing `) FROM TABLE_XYZ;`

I tried looking into the documentation but could not find any. Does there exist a short-cut to perform this action?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Column editor in Oracle Sql Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41718487/column-editor-in-oracle-sql-developer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mouse-aided solution, block selection.

[image]

If you're in a Code Editor (pl/sql), you can use Ctrl+Shift+PgUp/Down to add cursors.

[image]